# custom tableView UICell only showing a sliver

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a custom Tableview cell, but only a narrow horizontal sliver of the cell is showing up on the simulator.

This happens even if I change the simulator to a larger device. And I've checked to make sure that the outlets are connected.

```
import UIKit

class EstimatedIncomeCell: UITableViewCell {

static let identifier = "EstimatedIncomeCell"



@IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!


@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
}
```

From the ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


@IBOutlet weak var incomesTableView: UITableView!

var amountOfIncomes = 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.incomesTableView.delegate = self
    self.incomesTableView.dataSource = self
    
    self.registerTableViewCell()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = incomesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EstimatedIncomeCell") as? EstimatedIncomeCell{
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

private func registerTableViewCell(){
    let incomeCell = UINib(nibName: "EstimatedIncomeCell", bundle: nil)
    
    self.incomesTableView.register(incomeCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "EstimatedIncomeCell")
    
}
```

}

[for the textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxsLf.jpg)

[for the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h59hT.jpg)

Comment: You need to show us your constraints setup in your EstimatedIncomeCell xib.

Comment: @DonMag Thank you for informing me. Just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through some auto-layout tutorials...

For both your TextField and Button:

- the **orange** indicates you've moved the element away from its constraints
- you have **negative** Top constraints, which means you're telling auto-layout to position the elements ***outside the bounds of the cell***
- neither one has a **Bottom** constraint

[image]

[image]

So, for your TextField:

- change the `Top Space to: Superview` from `-46` to `13`
- delete the `Align Center Y to: Superview` constraint
- add a Bottom constraint of `13`

For your Button:

- delete the `Align Center Y to: Superview` constraint
- delete the `Top Space to: Superview` constraint

That *should* get you at least close to what you want.

Comment: It looks a lot better now! I'm gonna study Autolayouts some more to get a better understanding of it.